# What does _acmdln_dll?

Tags: disassembly, windows, x86

Does somebody knows what `_acmdln_dll` is ? I could not find any useful documentation about that.

I am asking because I have the following line in the assembly which I try to analyze:

```
 MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS : [_acmdln_dll]
```

After that line I have in register `EAX` the path of the current process. So my assumption is now the `_acmdln_dll` stores somehow the path as string sequence.
Is that true ?

Can someone confirm that or does someone know more informations about `_acmdln_dll` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are global variables provided by the Microsoft run time library. Here is an excerpt of *[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770586.aspx)* on-line documentation speaking about the `_acmdln` variable:

> **`_acmdln`**, `_tcmdln`, `_wcmdln`
>
> **These variables store the complete command line. `_acmdln` stores the data as a character string**. `_wcmdln` stores the data as a wide character string. `_tcmdln` can be defined as either `_acmdln` or `_wcmdln`, depending on which is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

**well after rereading the original question it appears both my answer

and the answer i followed up do not give an answer to the original question

original question asks about acmdln_dll which is nowhere to be found in vs crt

i leave the answer as it is assuming the suffix __dll to be in code that is not native ms like from reactos here**

http://code.google.com/p/reactos-mirror/source/browse/trunk/reactos/lib/crtdll/misc/GetArgs.c?spec=svn271&r=271

**the answer below is pertinent to _acmdln without the suffix _dll see edit 3 also**

the `complete source code` is available to you for `acmdln` if you have installed even the `express version of visual studio`.

`compile a simple hello world with debug info` **/Zi**  and view the source code as to what it is

source file in crt directory of visual studio

```
DS:[00408018]=7C812FBD (kernel32.GetCommandLineA)
Jump from __tmainCRTStartup+9B
crt0.c:252.  _tcmdln = (_TSCHAR *)GetCommandLineT();
```

here is a relevent disassembly
notice the result of GetCommandline being moved to acmdln a global

```
/*
 * command line, environment, and a few other globals
 */

    #ifdef WPRFLAG
    wchar_t *_wcmdln;           /* points to wide command line */
    #else  /* WPRFLAG */
    char *_acmdln;              /* points to command line */
    #endif  /* WPRFLAG */

    char *_aenvptr = NULL;      /* points to environment block */
    wchar_t *_wenvptr = NULL;   /* points to wide environment block */
```

disassembly

```
004014D9           CALL    newheapt._amsg_exit
004014DE           POP     ECX
004014DF           CALL    NEAR DWORD PTR DS:[<&KERNEL32.GetCommandLineA>]      ; _tcmdln = (_TSCHAR *)GetCommandLineT();
004014E5           MOV     DWORD PTR DS:[_acmdln], EAX
004014EA           CALL    newheapt.__crtGetEnvironmentStringsA                 ; _tenvptr = (_TSCHAR *)GetEnvironmentStringsT();
004014EF           MOV     DWORD PTR DS:[_aenvptr], EAX
004014F4           CALL    newheapt._setargv                                    ; if ( _tsetargv() < 0 )
004014F9           TEST    EAX, EAX
004014FB           JNS     SHORT newheapt.00401505
004014FD           PUSH    8                                                    ; _amsg_exit(_RT_SPACEARG);
004014FF           CALL    newheapt._amsg_exit
00401504           POP     ECX
00401505           CALL    newheapt._setenvp                                    ; if ( _tsetenvp() < 0 )
0040150A           TEST    EAX, EAX
0040150C           JNS     SHORT newheapt.00401516
0040150E           PUSH    9                                                    ; _amsg_exit(_RT_SPACEENV);
```

**edit 3**

from a general search it seems that this is defined in crtdll.dll

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>grep -rs _acmdln_dll *
Binary file crtdll.dll matches
Binary file dllcache/crtdll.dll matches
^C
C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

loading the dll in ollydbg _acmdln_dll is exactly same as _acmdln

```
73D91D02                   |> \FF15 4410>CALL    NEAR DWORD PTR DS:[<&KERNEL32.GetCommandLineA>]      ; [GetCommandLineA
73D91D08                   |.  A3 CC3EDB>MOV     DWORD PTR DS:[_acmdln_dll], EAX
73D91D0D                   |.  FF15 4010>CALL    NEAR DWORD PTR DS:[<&KERNEL32.GetEnvironmentStrings>>; [GetEnvironmentStrings
73D91D13                   |.  A3 D03EDB>MOV     DWORD PTR DS:[73DB3ED0], EAX
73D91D18                   |.  FF15 0411>CALL    NEAR DWORD PTR DS:[<&KERNEL32.GetVersion>]           ;  kernel32.GetVersion
```

and this crtdll.dll seems to be from an older windows sdk a brief google yields one page which alludes crtdll.lib belonging to windows sdk 3.5 era

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/94248